# display specific category on page

Tags: categories

I have been trying to get the posts from a certain category to show on a specific page. i am using the rock star theme and figured i could create a new page, use it as the template and use the coding from the Archive page and just make it read the contests category and show them on that page like they show on the normal category/contests page. here is the coding from the archive page if anyone could help id be so grateful!

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Archive pages
 *
 * Learn more: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package Catch Themes
 * @subpackage Rock Star
 * @since Rock Star 0.3
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <header class="page-header" style="animation-delay: 0.3s; animation-duration: 2s;">
            <?php
                the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );
                the_archive_description( '<div class="taxonomy-description">', '</div>' );
            ?>
        </header>

        <div id="archive-blog-wrapper" class="archive-blog-wrapper three-columns">

            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php
                    /* Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                     * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                     * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
                ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div><!-- archive-blog-wrapper -->

        <?php rock_star_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`WP_QUERY`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to achieve that.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <header class="page-header" style="animation-delay: 0.3s; animation-duration: 2s;">
        <?php
            the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );
            the_archive_description( '<div class="taxonomy-description">', '</div>' );
        ?>
    </header>

    <div id="archive-blog-wrapper" class="archive-blog-wrapper three-columns">

        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
        <?php
        //set up a new query
        $category_query=new wp_query( array( 'cat' => 'put your category id here');

      while ( $category_query->have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php
                /* Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                 * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                 * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
            ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div><!-- archive-blog-wrapper -->

    <?php rock_star_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```